# Form tries to submit as get rather than post when using Jquery validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

im using the Jquery validation plugin (http://jqueryvalidation.org/) to do some simple front end form validation. As far as i can see its all working, however now my form seems to be attempting to send as get rather than post (all data saved into query string and reloaded on page). Its really weird, I cant figure out what ive done wrong here

**HTML**

```
 <form id ="form1">

    <p>What do you do for a living?</p>
    <select name="Job">         
    <option value="4">job4</option>
    <option value="3">job3</option>
    <option value="2">job2</option>
    <option value="1">job1</option>
    </select> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id ="formButton">
 </form>
```

**Javascript**

```
var form = $("form");
form.validate();
$("#button").click(function () {
    var isValid = form.valid();
    if (isValid) {
        console.log("Valid: " + form.valid() + "form validation passed");
        var frm = $('#form1');
        frm.submit(function (ev) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "form_validation.php",
                data: frm.serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.error) {
                        alert(data.error);
                    } else {
                        alert(data.message + " " + data.sql);
                    }
                }

            });
        });
        ev.preventDefault();
    } else {
        console.log("form validation failed");
    }
});
```

Comment: What version of `jQuery` are you using ?

Comment: im using version 2.1.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the version of jQuery you are using. The default `method` or `type` used for the request is `GET`.

In your case if you are using a version of jQuery that is `> 1.9.0` used `method` property instead.

Otherwise the `type` property should work as is.

`method: 'POST'`

Comment: yeah im using 2.1.4.. should i switch to an earlier version?

Comment: You can stick to the same version. But use `method: 'POST'` instead of `type: 'POST'` . That should take care of it.

Comment: yeah i think thats got it. There was a small bug in the syntax of my JS too, was breaking the callback function

Answer (score 2):

I would change your HTML form a bit

```
<form id ="form1" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">

<p>What do you do for a living?</p>
<select name="Job">         
<option value="4">job4</option>
<option value="3">job3</option>
<option value="2">job2</option>
<option value="1">job1</option>
</select> 
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

This works when I do it.

Comment: tried that, get the following errors: ReferenceError: ev is not defined javascript.js:31:8
ReferenceError: validateForm is not defined 
A form was submitted in the windows-1252 encoding which cannot encode all Unicode characters, so user input may get corrupted. To avoid this problem, the page should be changed so that the form is submitted in the UTF-8 encoding either by changing the encoding of the page itself to UTF-8 or by specifying accept-charset=utf-8 on the form element.